# How do I create a Python SQLite login and create account that validates against a database and then prompts the user another database

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm preparing for my coursework and I don't know how to create a login database that will be validated against the database... The create account bit should add a new row in my column and the password must be strong enough. Once I get that bit sorted, i'd like to direct the user to another database that i've already created... i'm thinking of importing the other database into the login sql file. I'd appreciate it if you guys can help me.. At the moment it doesn't work but this is what i have, it's not done yet but i'm guessing it's very wrong...:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

def user_menu():
print("Login menu")
print()
print("1. Login")
print("2. Create Account")
print("0. Exit Program")

def get_user_menu_choice():
accepted = False
while not accepted:
    choice = int(input("Please select an option: "))
    if 0 <= choice <= 2:
        accepted = True
    else:
        print("Pleae enter a valid value:")
return choice

def query(sql,data):
with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql,data)
    db.commit()

def insert_data(values):
sql = "insert into Product (name,password) values(?,?)"
query(sql,values)

def main():
finished = False
while not finished:
    user_menu()
    choice = get_user_menu_choice()
    if choice == 1:
        # Get login details from user
        user = input('User: ')
        password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
        # Connect to database
        db = sqlite3.connect('DATABASE') 
        c = db.cursor()
        # Execute sql statement and grab all records where the "usuario" and
        # "senha" are the same as "user" and "password"
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM Product', (user, password))
        # If nothing was found then c.fetchall() would be an empty list, 
which
        # evaluates to False 
        if c.fetchall():
            print('Welcome')
        else:
            print('Login failed')

    elif choice == 2:
        name = input("Please enter name of name ")
        password = input("Please enter the passsword {0}: ".format(name))
        insert_data((name,password))
    elif choice == 0:
        finished = True
    else:
        finished = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
DATABASE = "userlogins.db"
main()
```

#

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert_data(values):
    sql = "insert into Product (name,password) values(?,?)"
    query(sql,values)
here what is query(sql,values) for??
here you passing only one argument to function insert_data

and here you are calling this function with two arguments.
so it would not insert data
elif choice == 2:
    name = input("Please enter name of name ")
    password = input("Please enter the password {0}: ".format(name))
    insert_data((name,password))
```

so in definition of def insert_data you should write exactly

def insert_data(value1,value2):
       sql = "insert into Product (name,password) values(?,?)"
       cursor.excecute(sql)